# AngularJS: how to watch tab selection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angularjs tab and pane example components

```
angular.module('components', []).
    directive('tabs', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope, $element) {
                var panes = $scope.panes = [];

                $scope.select = function(pane) {
                    angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                        pane.selected = false;
                    });
                    pane.selected = true;
                }

                this.addPane = function(pane) {
                    if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
                        panes.push(pane);
                    }
                },
                template:
                    '<div class="tabbable">' +
                        '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
                                '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
                            '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                        '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
                    '</div>',
                replace: true
            };
        }).
    directive('pane', function() {
        return {
            require: '^tabs',
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: { title: '@' },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
                tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
            },
            template:
                '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
                '</div>',
            replace: true
        };
    })
```

**SomePage.html**

```
<tabs>
    <pane title="Datos Generales">
        <div ng-include src="'/resources/js/page/running/admin/templates/update-data.html'"></div>
    </pane>
    <pane title="Localización">
        <div ng-include src="'/resources/js/page/running/admin/templates/update-location.html'"></div>
    </pane>
    <pane title="Datos Contacto">
        <div ng-include src="'/resources/js/page/running/admin/templates/update-contacts.html'"></div>
    </pane>
    <pane title="Variantes">
        <div ng-include src="'/resources/js/page/running/admin/templates/update-variants.html'"></div>
    </pane>
</tabs>
```

In the second pane there is a GoogleMap. I would like to refresh the google map when the second pane is selected.

I don't know how to get selected pane in the controller. I've tried `$scope.panes` but is `undefined`

Comment: Which controller needs to know?  A controller that surrounds the tabs element?  A controller inside the ng-include'd update-location.html?

Comment: A controller that surrounds the tabs element

Comment: Note that as of v 0.5 (and possibly earlier), the tab directive can take a 'select' attribute which is a '&' attribute, evaluated in parent scope, so it's no longer necessary to modify the ui-bootstrap code.

Comment: Can you please look into this issue [Angular Tab Disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311923/how-to-move-to-second-tab-on-click-of-a-button-when-using-angularjs-tab-directiv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are three ways you could solve your problem:

1. define a method on your controller, specify that method in an attribute on the tabs element, use the '&' syntax on the tabs directive's isolate scope definition to enable the directive to call the specified method when a pane is selected.
2. define an object on your controller's scope with a "selectedPane" property.  Use the '=' sytnax on the  tabs directive's isolate scope definition to enable two-way databinding.  Set this property whenever a pane is selected.
3. have the tabs directive [$emit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$emit) an event, and have your controller listen for it using $on.

**Update**: @qopuir asked for more details about option 1. 

Suppose the controller method is something like the following:

```
$scope.paneChanged = function(pane) {
    $scope.selectedPane = pane
    ...
}
```

On the tabs element, we'll specify this function with attribute `pane-changed`:

```
<tabs pane-changed="paneChanged(selectedPane)">
```

Then, the tabs directive can use the '&' syntax to call this method:

```
.directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { paneChanged: '&' },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

            $scope.select = function(pane) {
                angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                    pane.selected = false;
                });
                pane.selected = true;
                $scope.paneChanged({selectedPane: pane});
            }
```

Comment: I've tried option 3, but there's still a problem. The listener refreshes the map before it is rendered, so google map is printed wrong.
How could this be solved? I am using AngularUI for Google Maps.

Comment: If you have a directive handling your google map, add a controller to that directive and have it $emit the event after the map renders (hopefully google maps provides a callback or some event you can bind() to in order to know when rendering is complete.)  In the callback or event handler, be sure to call $scope.apply().  If you don't have a callback or event to trigger off of, then the best you can do is use $timeout somewhere.  The timeout handler could just be called after x milliseconds, or maybe it could check for something in the DOM that would indicate the map is rendered.

Comment: Finally I've used $timeout, because callback didn't work well. But I am not convinced with option 3. I prefer option 1 but I don't know how to configure tabs directive to accept a parameter specifying method. Could you detail how to implement that solution?

Comment: @qopuir if you never hide the tab content, and place  the unselected ones off screen and still visible, the map can determine the dimensions of container ( which it can't when hidden) and you won;t need to trigger a resize on map. This has long been a recommended approach for jQueryUI tabs  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F

Comment: @qopuir, see my updated answer for an example of how to implement option 1.

Comment: Thank you very much mark!! And also thank you @charlietfl!! I've used a combination of both solutions. Mark's solution to pan to marker on tab selection and @charlieftfl's solution to avoid resizing google map every time a tab is selected

Comment: Can you please look into this issue [Angular Tab disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311923/how-to-move-to-second-tab-on-click-of-a-button-when-using-angularjs-tab-directiv)